# git: cloning problem via jupyter notebook

Tags: python, git, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to clone a file in my repo to a jupyter notebook. This is for a final project which is a requirement.

The jupyter notebook has a set of programs that will run correctly if a module in my repo is cloned to the directory of the jupyter notebook. Our professor said that he will simply look at the jupyter notebook and clone it using `git clone` inside the notebook. if it doesn't clone, 10% deduction.

so i tried typing the following in my notebook

```
!git clone 'SSH of git repo' *filename*
```

However when I did, the following errors occurred:

```
Cloning into *filename*..
remote: Enumerating objects: 23, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (23/23), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (20/20), done.
remote: Total 23 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (23/23), 16.62 KiB | 218.00 KiB/s, done.
fatal: premature end of pack file, 127 bytes missing
warning: die() called many times. Recursion error or racy threaded death!
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Is there something I am doing wrong with regards to cloning? In theory if I use the terminal, it should work. But why isn't it working when using the jupyter notebook?

Comment: I don't understand properly what are you going to achieve but I think you need to pull from your remote repository

Comment: do you have a local repository and you want to add files (pull) from remote repository?

Comment: you can't use clone to get single file from your remote repository. You can use clone to download whole repository

Comment: sorry. just a bit of context: there is a folder and inside that folder is a 1 project file. i have a python module in a remote git repository and i need to clone that to the folder where the project file. i need to clone it using some cli commands in the jupyter notebook. but those errors show up

Comment: ah, okay, understand

Answer (score -1):

If in case you encounter this problem, I still don't know why this is happening but i found that the following codes will work:

```
!git clone --depth=1 `ssh url`
```